How to build an R binary package for Windows from Linux?
I have an R package that includes code which requires compilation, however not all my end users have compilers installed in their computers, so I am creating a binary.
The end users use Windows, so I need a Windows binary. If I were to do it locally it would be okay because I also have that system. However, I have a GitHub repo where we usually run GitHub Actions with every package version bump so that the latest version is pushed to our internal repository. Nevertheless, I need a Windows binary pushed through that process.
Is there a way to run cross compilation from Linux (Ubuntu image) to Windows in a GitHub Action?
In other words, I think this would not work directly from Ubuntu:
devtools::build(binary = TRUE)

I solved this by setting up runs-on: windows-latest in my YAML file in order to create the Windows binary.
